# Update the generated shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Is it possible to change the shortcode that was generated by the WP plugin? The reason I want to change the shortcode is because I want to use the same shortcode for my local, dev and production.(No if statement). I checked the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` table but I did not see anything that resembles the shortcode that was recently generated.

I tried searching previous StackOverflow questions but I did not see anything that matches my question.

Example: From `[smartslider3 slider="2"]` to `[smartslider3 slider="3"]`

Scenario:
During development, I may create a lot of posts/shortcodes to test different data. Created until slider="10". Now I push the code to test server, I need to create a new post/shortcode. But since the order is not the same, on the test server, the next shortcode generated would be slider="2" or something. I want to change the generated shortcode of test server from slider="2" to slider="10" to match my local code.

If possible, I don't want to do something like:

```
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'local') {
    echo '[smartslider3 slider="10"]';
}
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'staging') {
    echo '[smartslider3 slider="2"]';
}
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'production') {
    echo '[smartslider3 slider="2"]';
}
```

Note, this is not smartslider specific but all plugins that generates shortcode. If it is not possible, they I may need to do if else statement.

Comment: Your question it is not clear. Could you please provide some more info? What you mean by `change the shortcode that was generated by the WP Plugin?`. You mean when you list all the smartslider slides you created, the one you want to have the `slider="3"` or you want to replace the shortcode `[smartslider3 slider="2"]` already used in some of your posts/pages with the shortcode `[smartslider3 slider="3"]`?

Comment: I will try to update my question.

Comment: The slider ID it should saved in the database _(I guess in custom tables created by the plugin)_. You could always update manually the ID of a record in staging env to much your local, but this is not a good solution, as the record IDs tend to be auto-increment integers, and sooner or later you will have troubles. For such a case, you may try to export your local env database tables related to the slideshow and import them to the staging environment. This way I suppose you will maintain the same IDs in both sides.

Comment: In worst case scenario, you may use content filters, to replace the shortcode id programmatically, but again this is not clear solution.

Comment: I see. I did consider exporting the data rather than importing them instead. But I wanted to ask others if this is possible. Thank you for taking the time to answer.